# How do I sanitize user SQL input in a shiny app without adding unnecessary quotation marks?

Tags: sql, r, sql-injection, r-dbi

I am building a shiny app in R, through which users have the ability to edit the content of a SQL database. Namely, our app contains free-text fields, and whenever the user input to those fields is modified, so is the underlying database. Of course, we are concerned about SQL injection and would like to take steps to help guard against it.

Currently, the server code looks like this. We are using the `DBI` package to interface with the database.

```
update_query <- paste0("UPDATE ", select_var$table_name, " SET ", select_var$var_name, " = ", insert,  " WHERE ", select_id, " = '", select_value, "'")
query <- dbSendStatement(con, update_query)
dbClearResult(query)
```

Four of the five dynamic components of the query are generated from the code itself and do not need to be sanitized, but `insert` is the user-supplied freeform text.

To help guard against SQL injection, we wrapped `insert` inside `dbQuoteString`. I understand simply quoting inputs does not fully protect against injection, but that is not the point. So `dbQuoteString` works, except for when the user-supplied input starts and/or ends with a quotation mark. For example:

```
insert <- "'a'"
update_query <- paste0("UPDATE ", select_var$table_name, " SET ", select_var$var_name, " = ", dbQuoteString(insert),  " WHERE ", select_id, " = '", select_value, "'")
query <- dbSendStatement(con, update_query)
dbClearResult(query)
```

This successfully inserts the escaped string, but when the table is loaded into R's memory again, the value for the cell in question is now `"'''a'''"` (note the added quotation marks), rather than `"'a'"`. Thus when the user restarts the app and needs to edit that input, he has to delete the extra characters before making his desired edit. Is there any way to ensure that escaping the user input does not actually change the content itself?

The documentation for `dbQuoteString` states that "When passing the returned object again to `dbQuoteString()` as `x` argument, it is returned unchanged". Yet if the result is coerced to character (similar to what happens when the table is read in to R's memory again), it changes:

```
> dbQuoteString(con, "'a'")
<SQL> '''a'''

> dbQuoteString(con, dbQuoteString(con, "'a'"))
<SQL> '''a'''

> dbQuoteString(con, as.character(dbQuoteString(con, "'a'")))
<SQL> '''''''a'''''''
```

How to avoid these extra quotation marks while also implementing *some* protection against SQL injection?

Edit: I should have mentioned this in the original question, after receiving the comments and answers, I should note that parametrized queries lead to the same behavior as well.

```
 update_query <- paste0("UPDATE ", select_var$table_name, " SET ", select_var$var_name, " = ", "?", " WHERE ", select_id, " = '", select_value, "'")
query <- dbSendStatement(con, update_query)
dbBind(query, list(insert))
dbClearResult(query)
```

Comment: And why have you ruled out the use of `dbSendStatement` with `?` parameters? You basically don't have to change anything. Replace the value in your query with `?` and pass the additional param `params` to your function. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I'm a staunch supporter of "never `paste` user-_data_ into a query", preferring to do parameterized queries all the time. It adds no overhead, makes the queries a little simpler to read, simplifies server-side query optimization caching, and ***completely*** mitigates this over-quoting problem. See [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries) (and XKCD's [*Exploits of a Mom*](https://xkcd.com/327/)).

Comment: Thank you for the comments, parametrized queries do not work either, so now I am ruling them out. I've updated the question

Comment: How are you loading the result? It seems odd that you're calling dbQuoteString multiple times on the string. I would expect you to call it once on the `insert` and in any `where` clauses when retrieving, but I wouldn't expect you to try to quote it  again when loading it.

Comment: Upon startup the tables are read into R as a data table with `dbReadTable(con, table_name) %>% as.data.table()` (the same behavior happens even if I do not cast to a data.table). I would call `dbQuoteString` multiple times if the user edits the value, restarts the app, and edits it again. When the cell is pre-populated after restart, there are additional quotation marks. Perhaps the issue lies with reading in the table from the database rather than with inserting into it.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `dbQuoteString`, you probably want to use `dbBind` (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DBI/versions/0.5-1/topics/dbBind).

Something like:

```
insert <- "'a'"
update_query <- paste0("UPDATE ", select_var$table_name, " SET ", select_var$var_name, " = ?",  " WHERE ", select_id, " = '", select_value, "'")
query <- dbSendStatement(con, update_query)
dbBind(query, list(insert))
dbClearResult(query)
```

`dbBind(query, list(insert))` means replace the parameter that is just a question mark with the value in `insert` and properly sanitize it.

Or, as pointed out by @markalex, you can put the parameters in the `dbSendStatement`. Something like:

```
insert <- "'a'"
update_query <- paste0("UPDATE ", select_var$table_name, " SET ", select_var$var_name, " = ?",  " WHERE ", select_id, " = '", select_value, "'")
query <- dbSendStatement(con, update_query, params = list(insert))
dbClearResult(query)
```

Most (all?) modern programming languages will have a way of parameterizing queries like this.

This has a few advantages over simply escaping the values manually. If you never put any user-input in your queries at all, it is less likely you will make a mistake by doing one incorrectly. It might do other clever escaping besides just quotes (and you don't have to worry about this). It allows you to treat string-input and non-string input the same (you don't need to write quotes around the parameter at all). Your DB might be able to optimize these queries better (since at least with some drivers it will pass the query and parameters separately so the DB can avoid recalculating execution plans).

Comment: Even `dbBind` is not [necessary](https://dbi.r-dbi.org/reference/dbsendstatement). You could pass parameters straight to `dbSendStatement`.

Comment: I was not aware of that. Thank you. I have adjusted the answer to include that as an option.

Comment: ... and `dbExecute` and `dbGetQuery`, neither of which require `dbClearResult`. (And since `DBI` doesn't really do multiple open result-sets, it's not as if you can keep two+ update-query resultsets alive and re-bind to one or the other, so I have yet to find an example where using `dbSendStatement`/`dbClearResult` has any advantage over `dbExecute`, same for `dbGetQuery`.)

Comment: Thank you, but parametrized queries lead to the same behavior. I have updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: You're using `?` for the conditional but not for setting the value. Fix that, bound-params can be used there as well. I suggest something like: `paste0("UPDATE ", select_var$table_name, " SET ", select_var$var_name, " = ? WHERE ", select_id, " = ?")`, and then do `dbExecute(con, update_query, params=list(select_var$var_name, select_value))`, though to be candid, allowing the user to set the ***table name*** is a HUGE liability. You should really verify it is one of a small set of known tables before submitting this query.